# How to show a Tooltip outside of form

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get a tooltip to show that is not constrained to the form itself. In other words - a tooltip that is visible when the form is not in focus.

I have tried

```
ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True
```

but that does not work. Here is the code that I am using currently:

```
ToolTip1.Show("TEXT", Me, New Point(1024, 768))
```

This shows the tooltip wonderfully, but the tooltip goes away when the form has lost focus.

Comment: What are you trying to display in this tooltip?  Maybe a `ToolTip` isn't the most appropriate choice.

Comment: I do a lot of copying and pasting for work and I'm trying to display my clipboard text in the tooltip. But because I have to tab in and out of multiple windows, I need the tooltip to be visible on top of all of the windows.

Comment: I'd suggest a separate form.  You might find the custom form class [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890) helpful.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I'm so dumb. Can you put that as an answer so that I can mark it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate form with `TopMost` set to `True` is probably the way to go, rather than a `ToolTip`.  If you want a form that won't take focus when displayed, try [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890).